# How to update Ionic 2 Tabs Badges by binding property from an Angular 2 service?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am trying to get a value from a service into tabs component whenever the value in the service is updated, and if possible, bind **cartNumber in cart.service.ts** to **cartNumber in tabs.ts**. My use case is this:

### [Screenshot of my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDAHQ.png)

By tapping the 'Add to Cart' button, the 'Cart' tab in the middle should update the badge number to the corresponding item number in cartNumber

> cart.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class CartService {

  public cartNumber: number;

  constructor() {}

  getCartItems() {
    // returns list of items in shopping cart
  }

  addToCart(id, quantity){
    // updates the shopping cart with new items
  }
```

> tabs.ts

```
import { CartService } from '../cart/cart.service';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})
export class TabsPage {
  // this tells the tabs component which Pages
  // should be each tab's root Page

  tab1Root: any = HomePage;
  tab2Root: any = CartPage;
  tab3Root: any = ProfilePage;

  public cartNumber: number;

  constructor() {
  }

}
```

So what is the best way to 'bind' the **cart.service cartNumber** value to my **tabs component's cartNumber** so that the value will update whenever there is a change in **cart.service cartNumber**?

I have tried ngOnChanges but it does not seem to work. EventEmitters does not seem to work in this case. Or that I could be wrong in any of my understanding in any of these methods.

Comment: Check Ionic 2 [events](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/util/Events/)

Comment: @SurajRao Thanks ! I will try this

Comment: could you put your template, where you binding cartNumber

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks [Suraj Rao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4826457/suraj-rao) for the suggestion of using [Ionic 2 Events](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/util/Events/)

I couldn't find a way to communicate between different components as stated, this definitely did the job. A very clean and elegant solution without having to use $watch or run through $scope via injections like in angular 1.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `tabs.ts`, you can inject the instance of `CartService` inside the `TabsPage` constructor using: below code:

```
import { CartService } from '../cart/cart.service';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})
export class TabsPage {
  // this tells the tabs component which Pages
  // should be each tab's root Page

  tab1Root: any = HomePage;
  tab2Root: any = CartPage;
  tab3Root: any = ProfilePage;

  public cartNumber: number;

  constructor(cartService : CartService ) {//It will be automatically injected by the Ionic framework

  }

  //Somewhere in your code you can do this :
  this.cartService.addToCart(/*parameters*/);


}
```

In order to make that work, make sure `CartService` is listed as a provider in app.module.ts file.